# Yii: JavaScript files I render don't do a thing on my page

Tags: jquery, yii, clientscript

I'm using Yii and I want to render some javaScript files in my view, i can render them with the following code

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile(Yii::app()->request->baseUrl . '/protected/components/js/ForCreatePage.js',CClientScript::POS_HEAD);
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile(Yii::app()->request->baseUrl . '/protected/components/js/createPageReady.js',CClientScript::POS_READY);
```

But when i try to use a function from it or use the ready file, the code don't do anything

Part of the files
ForCreatePage:

```
function link_to_generated(data) {  
    alert($(data).find('ff_result').text());
}
```

createPageReady:

```
(function() {
    amount_of_pages = 1;

    $("#for-movie").css('width',(($('#for-movie-container-2').width()-10)+'px'));

    ... // more code inside the file

});
```

Comment: Do you get any error on the console? Can you see the files being loaded in the network tab?

Comment: No, don't see something there

Answer (score 2):

Your project `protected` folder can (and by default it is so) contain `.htaccess` file with folowing content

```
deny from all
```

this means that all requests to this folder(and subfolders) will be denied. You should see in browser console error, that requested files can't be retrieved

Unless there is another `.htaccess` in `js` directory that explicitly allows access to it. E.g.

```
allow from all
```

Use `CAssetManager` together with `CClientScript`. Here is how I use it within widgets:

```
$assets=Yii::app()->assetManager->publish(__DIR__.'/assets/');
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCssFile($assets.'/css/styles.css');
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile($assets.'/js/scripts.js');
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CAssetManager

Comment: how do you push your file into assets? and from my controller when  i use that code he don't find the path, it ends on /controller/assets/

Comment: `CAssetManager::publish` pushes files for you. Just feed proper path to directory. `__DIR__.'/assets/'` - is path to assets of my widget. It can be any path. It can be retrived from anywhere. In you case can be `Yii::getPathOfAlias('application.controller.assets')`. But I think storing js-files within controllers dir is not proper way.